# rm in ifeq condition - Makefile - error seen

Tags: makefile

I am trying to use rm command in ifeq condition in a makefile, but I was encountering error saying missing separator. May I pls know if we can't use rm command in makefile if it's a non-target.

To avoid removing work/*.elf manually, I tried adding the below highlighted line in cfg.mk, however I was getting ‘missing separator error’ (at that highlighted line)

```
ifeq ($(EN_DBG_MSGS),1)
rm $(CFG_DIR)/work/*.elf       #throws error
export CARGS += -DDBG_MSGS_FLAG 
endif
```

I even tried below line but unsuccessful.

```
if [ -a $(CFG_DIR)/work/$(TEST).elf ]; then rm -r $(CFG_DIR)/work/$(TEST).elf; fi
```

May I pls know if I am missing anything here.

rgds
Kishore

Comment: `rm` is a shell command, you cannot invoke it outside the rules. Well, you *can*, but... Why do you not want to put it in a rule?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I got it resolved using $(shell rm $(CFG_DIR)/work/*.elf)